# Different on hover visual state for BS_OWNERDRAW buttons

Tags: windows, winapi

I have a BS_OWNERDRAW button created with:

```
HWND hwndClose = CreateWindow(WC_BUTTON, _T(""),
                    BS_PUSHBUTTON | BS_OWNERDRAW | WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE,
                    0, 0, 16, 16, win->hwndTocBox, (HMENU)IDC_TOC_CLOSE, ghinst, NULL);
```

I want to draw it differently when cursor is over the button. I was expecting to get WM_DRAWITEM message every time cursor enters/leaves my button but that doesn't seem to be the case. I only get it once even though standard windows button clearly have different visual state in the on hover case.

Is it possible to easily get windows to send WM_DRAWITEM when on hover state changes, without doing tedious things like subclassing the button window and manually handling WM_MOUSEMOVE/WM_MOUSELEAVE messages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a side-effect of ownerdraw.  The visual hover effect you get on a 'regular' button is actually only present when its visual style is enabled.  However, any control that has its ownerdraw style turned on will *not* get the visual style.  This is appcompat behavior, it cannot be disabled.  You'll have to do this the hard way.